# Borland command line tools -- environment variables?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

I've just installed some Borland software development tools on a Windows 98 VMware virtual machine.  I'm mainly using them for DOS programming.

They are BCC, BCC32, TLINK, and TLINK32.

My main problem is with the linkers.  I'd like to specify a library search path.  It can be done on the command line, but it would be more convenient to use an environment variable.

Microsoft tools use the LIB variable, but I have been unable to find a variable that works with the Borland linkers.  Maybe they don't exist?

I tried LIB, LIBS, and TLINK32 environment variables.  They did not appear to work.